# EF Code First - Entity joining multiple tables

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first

I currently have an EF class that is backed by a database view (joining multiple tables). To make it updatable, I need to change the class to be backed by a database table. I am using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First and can't figure out how to set up those relationships?

To simplify, I currently have a Categories class that returns the Category Name (Categories table) and Category Type Name (CategoryTypes table). These are both in the database view that I currently use. I want to change to a ViewModel that brings back both of these fields directly from their tables and joins properly, that way when a user updates a Category Name, EF should be able to properly handle the update (since it will be updating the table instead of the view). Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table is a table - it is a single database object. If you want to remove your view and replace it with a table you need to delete your current tables (`Categories` and `CategoryTypes`) and create a single table which will contain denormalized data. That is pretty bad solution and it will cause you problems in the whole application.

Just to simplify description: It is not possible to replace your view constructed by joins among several tables with a table and it is not possible to make your view updatable.

You are doing it wrong because you are obviously mapping view models directly to your database. Map `Catagories` and `CategoryTypes` to entities load `Category` with its `CategoryType` and flatten them to your view model in your application logic (or load the view model through projection). Once user updates your view model decompose it back to separate entities and save them.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav! We had discussed this as a possible solution, but we're still new enough not to be sure. So, it's nice to get your confirmation! Now, off to refactor!